my using my click event from front end dos not write to database
I have a database running in postgres, with the app itself in flask.
I have an event in flask which is supposed to insert some data into my data base as seen below, however despite commiting the data does not show up in my database.
How can I fix it so the data does persist in my database.
Below is my code in flask
conn = psycopg2.connect(database="postgres",
                                            user="root",
                                            host='localhost',
                                            password="dbpass",
                                            port=5432)
    cur = conn.cursor()


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/shift/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def shift():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        id = request.form['id']

        if not id:
            flash('ID is required!')
        else:
            t = datetime.now().hour
            day = datetime.now().date().isoformat()
            shift = 2
            if 8 <= t <=14:
                shift = 1
                cur.execute("INSERT INTO shift (date, employee_id, shift_number) values (%s, %s, %s)", (day, id, shift))
                conn.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('index'))

    return render_template('shift.html')

here in my frontend in case anything is wrong with it
<form action="" method="post">
        <label for="title">Log your shift</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="id"
               placeholder="Enter work id"
               value="{{ request.form.id}}"></input>
        <br>
    <button type=”submit”> Submit </button>
</form>

thank you

Are you sure the INSERT is actually being done? Look at the Postgres log.

Also I would highly recommend going through the Tutorial in particular Define and Access the Database.

        t = datetime.now().hour
        day = datetime.now().date().isoformat()
        if 8 <= t <=14:
            shift = 1
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO shift (date, employee_id, shift_number) values (%s, %s, %s)", (day, id, shift))
            conn.commit()

the insert is only done between 8:00 and 15:00 in whatever time zone your command-line uses.
